# Plot that shows which attribute has the most effect on class?

Tags: r, machine-learning, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

I'm playing around with two datasets: [Mushrooms](http://repository.seasr.org/Datasets/UCI/arff/mushroom.arff) and [Breast Cancer](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs573x/labs/lab1/breast-cancer-wisconsin.arff).

I'm trying to form a **hypothesis** of which attribute would have the most effect on the class when making predictions about the class.

In Weka I visualize it like this:

For Mushrooms:

[image]

For Breast Cancer:

[image]

Looking at the above two. I can say that `Odor` attribute would have some effect on the class because it splits the two class variables in good amount. However, for breast cancer I can't say the same thing

**Question**

Is there a better illustration/graph that I can use (In R or SciKit) by looking at which I can hypothesize which attribute would have most effect on the class?

Note: I'm writing a paper that will use several learning algorithms on the dataset. But before I start running the algorithms on the dataset, I would like to make a hypothesis by visually looking at the dataset.

Comment: V2 and V3 seem to do fairly well. Not as well as odor in mushrooms, but still fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

- For discrete variables use a bar chart with the bars for different classes next to eachother, or on top of eachother with the alpha for each one turned down.
- For continuous variables you probably want a kernel density plot, or - if you've got a lot of data - a histogram with well-chosen bin widths.

I'd also recommend taking a look at scatterplot matrices. There are a lot of differences that only show up clearly when you consider variables in combination.